# Como alterar o meu nome de usuário?

Tags: suporte, perfil

Acredito que a maioria dos usuários não entram nessa rede com intenção de permanecer, normalmente é quando surge uma dúvida que necessita de resposta urgentemente. Eu, por exemplo, conheci o StackOverflow assim.

Criei uma conta rapidamente com o primeiro nick válido dentre os vários que tentei. Há aqueles usuários que fazem login pelo Facebook e tem um nick 'user00000'.

A minha dúvida é: Posso mudar o meu nome de usuário? Gostaria de frequentar a comunidade auxiliando outros usuários e respondendo perguntas que tenho conhecimento, mas gostaria de fazer isso com o mesmo nick que uso em fóruns.

Comment: Sim, pode! No seu perfil tem um link de edição.

Comment: Desculpa pela pergunta simples, eu pensei que aquele link era somente para editar o 'sobre mim', não tinha visto o nome de exibição. Obrigado.

Comment: Sem problemas! Não importa se a pergunta é simples ou não, o meta está aqui para esclarecer.

Comment: @bfavaretto tinha ideia que já tinha visto esta pergunta antes, mas não encontro duplicata.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sim, pode! No seu perfil tem um link de edição:

[image: printscreen]

Comment: +1+ por haver roubado o comentário-resposta do mod! Hello, mod?!

Comment: +1 por ter hackeado a conta do usuário para poder responder a pergunta

Comment: @Math usei um programa de invasão chamado Photoshop, mas não conte pra ninguem (mas o 0 do 170 da barra escura ficou 1px mais gordinho do que devia)!

Comment: Essa foi pro mod preguiçoso aprender... @brasofilo

Comment: Impeachment nele já!!! :D

Comment: @bigown Que isso? Vamos jogar pêssegos nele?

Comment: Em calda, por favor. Sem creme de leite.

Comment: Cadê o @brasofilo? http://i.stack.imgur.com/qM3Q5.gif

Comment: Se eu não for derrubado pelo golpe, prometo limpar as piadas. @Bacco

Comment: @Bacco, estou preparando o Photoshop da nova campanha :p

Comment: Pronto, a [campanha de empessegamento do mod está no ar](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18442069#18442069) c/c @bfav

Comment: @Bacco eu tentei seguir a sua resposta e ... simplesmente não achei o link editar lá. Tem alguma ideia do que pode ser? Já alterei o nome uma vez, mas agora não vejo o link.

Comment: @Cold, só é possível trocar o nome do usuário [1 vez por mês](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238866/why-cant-i-revert-my-display-name). Mas devia aparecer o link e dar o erro dos 30 dias, se fosse esse o caso.

Comment: @Cold pode ser que o link não tenha aparecido no seu perfil porque ele não aparece pelo meta sopt... O link pra editar, por algum motivo que desconheço, só está disponível no sopt principal...